# Laravel and Responsive Filemanager

Tags: php, laravel, responsive-filemanager

I have the next problem... I created a file "test.txt" inside:

```
http://foo.bar/assets/vendors/filemanager/
```

And I can access to this file, but I can't access to:

```
http://foo.bar/assets/vendors/filemanager/dialog.php?type=4&descending=false&lang=undefined&akey=key
```

When I put this on my routes.php:

```
Route::get("/assets/vendors/filemanager/dialog.php", function() {
    ob_start();
    require(public_path()."/assets/vendors/filemanager/dialog.php");
    return ob_get_clean();
});
```

Works "well" (that is, the error changes, because this patch doesn't catch the GET parameters...). The new error is:

```
Undefined variable: lang
```

Which can be easily corrected, but still, I can not make it work ... I guess the problem is that the route I have written before... (I don't know why this route is necessary)

I will really apreciate some help for this...

Url of filemanager: [www.responsivefilemanager.com](http://www.responsivefilemanager.com)

**Is this compatible with laravel...?**

Comment: There is a laravel package of responsive filemanager https://github.com/harimayco/Laravel-ResponsiveFileManager